# AlarmManager executed by big apps every 60 seconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

All the big apps like Whatsapp, Google Photos, Twitter vs schedules an Alarm using AlarmManager that repeat itself every 60 seconds. Like logs at below

V/AlarmManager: Adding Alarm{eaa38fe type 0 when 1503947374620 com.google.android.apps.photos} to Batch{90d5138 num=2 start=362534083 end=362714083}

V/AlarmManager: Adding Alarm{48da142 type 3 when 388800000 com.whatsapp} to Batch{c176a64 num=6 start=376940042 end=407673417}

V/AlarmManager: Adding Alarm{208254d type 0 when 1504035415055 com.twitter.android} to Batch{c5c3494 num=8 start=447514452 end=486345441 flgs=0x8}

I was wondering if there is a followed common design pattern used by these apps?

Comment: I suspect that those log messages do not mean what you think that they do.

Comment: I concur, *adding an alarm to batch* i.e. *scheduling an alarm to be executed alongside others later*. (Although I have no material evidence.)